# PHP Create an array based on two other arrays

Tags: php

I'm stuck on php program.
I've 2 array (1 is associative array) that comes from 2 different sources:

```
echo('<pre>');
var_dump(array1)
echo('<pre>');

array(5) {
  [2375]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Val"]=>
    string(1) "x"
    ["Desc"]=>
    string(13) "Lorem ipsum 1"
    ["gr_id"]=>
    string(2) "33"
  } 
  [2377]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Val"]=>
    string(1) "y"
    ["Desc"]=>
    string(13) "Lorem ipsum 2"
    ["gr_id"]=>
    string(2) "33"
  } 
  [2379]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Val"]=>
    string(1) "z"
    ["Desc"]=>
    string(13) "Lorem ipsum 3"
    ["gr_id"]=>
    string(2) "33"
  } 
  [2381]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Val"]=>
    string(1) "a"
    ["Desc"]=>
    string(13) "Lorem ipsum 4"
    ["gr_id"]=>
    string(2) "33"
  } 
  [2381]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Val"]=>
    string(34) "b"
    ["Desc"]=>
    string(46) "Lorem ipsum 5"
    ["gr_id"]=>
    string(2) "33"
  } 
  [3300]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Val"]=>
    string(34) "c"
    ["Desc"]=>
    string(46) "Lorem ipsum 5"
    ["gr_id"]=>
    string(2) "83"
  }
  [3302]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Val"]=>
    string(34) "d"
    ["Desc"]=>
    string(46) "Lorem ipsum 5"
    ["gr_id"]=>
    string(2) "83"
  }
```

```
var_dump(array2)
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "x"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "a"
}
```

As a result I need an associative array called array3 that have all the "Val" of the array1 that have the property "gr_id" == 33, and a second property called selected if this value is in array2:

```
echo('<pre>');
var_dump(array3)
echo('<pre>');

array(5) {
 [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Val"]=>
    string(1) "x"
    ["Selected"]=>
    bool(true)
  } 
[1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Val"]=>
    string(1) "y"
    ["Selected"]=>
    bool(false) 
  }
[2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Val"]=>
    string(1) "z"
    ["Selected"]=>
    bool(false) 
  } 
[3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Val"]=>
    string(1) "a"
    ["Selected"]=>
    bool(true) 
  } 
[4]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Val"]=>
    string(1) "b"
    ["Selected"]=>
    bool(false) 
  }
```

I tried foreach and for loop but I cannot came up with a solution:

```
$array3 = array();

foreach($rray1 as $Key => $Values){
 $tempArr = array();
 if($Values['gr_id'] == $GrID){
 foreach($array2 as $ValueSelected){
  $IsSelected = in_array($ValueSelected, $compareArr);
 }
 $tempArr[$GrID] = array(
  'Descr' => $Values['Val'],
  'Selected' => $IsSelected
 );
 array_push($array3 , $tempArr);
 }
}
```

Comment: Please present your arrays in form of a `var_export` (that results in PHP code we can _directly_ copy&paste to work with.)

Comment: `foreach($array2 as $ValueSelected)` - why would you loop over that second array, that makes little sense. You want to check if the `Val` from the first array, is contained in that second array - so that needs _just_ a call to `in_array`, not a loop.

Comment: $IsThere = in_array($array2, array1) if you mean like this that's set all to false

Comment: That doesn't make any sense at all - you'd be testing if your _full_ first array, contained the _full_ second one.

Answer (score 4):

```
$array1 = [
    2375 => ["Val" => "x", "Desc" => "Lorem ipsum 1", "gr_id" => "33"],
    2377 => ["Val" => "y", "Desc" => "Lorem ipsum 2", "gr_id" => "33"],
    2379 => ["Val" => "z", "Desc" => "Lorem ipsum 3", "gr_id" => "33"],
    2381 => ["Val" => "a", "Desc" => "Lorem ipsum 4", "gr_id" => "33"],
    2382 => ["Val" => "b", "Desc" => "Lorem ipsum 5", "gr_id" => "33"],
    3300 => ["Val" => "c", "Desc" => "Lorem ipsum 5", "gr_id" => "83"],
    3302 => ["Val" => "d", "Desc" => "Lorem ipsum 5", "gr_id" => "83"],
];

$array2 = ["x", "a"];

$GrID = "33"; // Define the desired "gr_id"

$array3 = [];

foreach ($array1 as $Key => $Values) {
    if ($Values['gr_id'] == $GrID) {
        $IsSelected = in_array($Values['Val'], $array2);
        $tempArr = [
            "Val" => $Values['Val'],
            "Selected" => $IsSelected,
        ];
        $array3[] = $tempArr;
    }
}

var_dump($array3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) is the function you are looking for.

```
function checkValue($value) {
    if($value['gr_id'] == 33) {
        $result['Val'] = $value['Val'];
        $result['Selected'] = false;
        if(in_array($value['Val'], $array2)) {
            $result['Selected'] = true;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

And call this function as

`$array3 = array_map('checkValue', $array1);`

Comment: And then filter out the null values from `$array3` (since if an element does not have gr_id of 33, the function does not return anything)

Answer (score 0):

How about using array_filter and array_walk :

```
<?php


$source = [
    "2375" => [
        "val" => "x",
        "desc" => "Lor",
        "gr_id" => "33"
    ],
    "2377" => [
        "val" => "y",
        "desc" => "Lor 2",
        "gr_id" => "33"
    ],
    "2378" => [
        "val" => "z",
        "desc" => "Lor 3",
        "gr_id" => "43"
    ],
    "2379" => [
        "val" => "j",
        "desc" => "Lor 4",
        "gr_id" => "33"
    ],
    "2388" => [
        "val" => "y",
        "desc" => "Lor 5",
        "gr_id" => "33"
    ],
];

$filter = ["x", "y"];

$result = array_filter($source, function($element){
    return $element['gr_id'] == '33';
});

array_walk($result, function(&$element) use ($filter){
    
    $element['selected'] = in_array($element['val'], $filter);
    unset($element['desc']);
    unset($element['gr_id']);
    
});


echo '<pre>';
var_dump($result);
echo '</pre>';
```